# Efficient way to map new values to a sql query (i.e 4 columns each with same credentials)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, left-join

First I am new to Postgres so I may be describing this problem incorrectly so please point me to an answer if it has already been answered.

I have a database with 10 columns. Lets say 4 columns all use the same codes for values (i.e the letter a, b, d, e) I want to rename all of these in the query to what they are matched with values in another table.

I have a very long approach at this stage involving a nested With  statements. Is there a easy way to go from say:

`table1`:

```
id    | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
------+------+------+------+------
Row_1 | a    | c    | d    | e
Row_2 | c    | c    | c    | c 
Row_3 | e    | d    | d    | c
```

Lookup Table:

```
code | value
-----+---------
a    | apple
b    | banana
c    | catfish
d    | dog
e    | egg
```

Desired result:

```
Row_1 | apple   | catfish | dog     | egg
Row_2 | catfish | catfish | catfish | dog
Row_3 | egg     | dog     | dog     | catfish
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145038/how-to-join-to-the-same-table-multiple-times This looks like the approach I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145038/how-to-join-to-the-same-table-multiple-times should basically work for you. But you want an `UPDATE`, which is a bit different:

Either way, `code` values in table `lookup` have to be `UNIQUE` for obvious reasons.

Updating a single column is simple:

```
UPDATE table1 t
SET    col1 = l.value
FROM   lookup l
WHERE  t.col1 = l.code;
```

If no match is found, the row it `table1` is not updated.
But running separate updates for every column is considerably more expensive than updating all columns at once - which is a bit more tricky:

```
UPDATE table1 t
SET    col1 = COALESCE(l1.value, t.col1)
     , col2 = COALESCE(l2.value, t.col2)
     , col3 = COALESCE(l3.value, t.col3)
     , col4 = COALESCE(l4.value, t.col4)
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN lookup l1 ON t.col1 = l1.code
LEFT   JOIN lookup l2 ON t.col2 = l2.code
LEFT   JOIN lookup l3 ON t.col3 = l3.code
LEFT   JOIN lookup l4 ON t.col4 = l4.code
WHERE  t1.id = t.id;
```

In this case, *all* rows are updated. While there can be `NULL` values in `table1` or missing values in `lookup` we need `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to not exclude rows from the update. So we need another instance of `table1` in the `FROM` clause and `LEFT JOIN` to that.

And the added `COALESCE` retains the original value for each individual column where no match was found. The optimal query depends on details not disclosed in your question ...

You might add another `WHERE` clause to exclude rows where nothing changes. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks:)